# Transform to Prenex Normal Conjunctive Form

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am trying to convert $∃x∀y(p(x, y) ⟺ q(x))$ into prenex conjunctive normal form.

These are the steps that I have taken thus far, however feel that I am missing something or went wrong somewhere.

Eliminate →, ⟺ and import negations

= ∃x∀y(p(x, y) → q(x)) ⋀ (q(x) → p(x, y))

= ∃x∀y(¬p(x, y) ⋁ q(x)) ⋀ (¬q(x) ⋁ p(x, y))

= ∃x∀y(p(x, y) ⋁ q(x)) ⋀ (¬q(x) ⋁ p(x, y))      * Renaming and using equivalences (b) – (c)

= ∀x∀y(p(x, y) ⋁ q(x)) ⋀ (¬q(x) ⋁ p(x, y))      * Resulting prenex CNF

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Demonstrating the tiniest morsel of effort on your own part might encourage others to make some effort for you

Comment: just to clarify this post is intend for someone to complete my homework/assignment. i have attempted some of the steps to try and transform the formula to pcnf, however requires guidance as I feel that I am missing something or went wrong somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, IamBrianNewell, for including some effort in your post.

Comment: The proposition starts out in prenex normal form.  PNF just means that all the quantifiers are on the outside of the expression.

Comment: Thanks @DanielV apologies, I noticed that I put the title incorrectly should be PCNF. Which is a little bit different PNF

Comment: The only change between the second and third expression is to drop a negation.  No equivalence allows that.  Likewise the fourth equation changes an existential to a universal, which is not equivalent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp ok fine I think I understand. So effectively, I would have gotten PCNF in the second line i.e.
∃x∀y(p(x, y) ⟷ q(x)) * Eliminate →, ⟷ and import negations
= ∃x∀y(p(x, y) → q(x)) ⋀ (q(x) → p(x, y))
= ∃x∀y(¬p(x, y) ⋁ q(x)) ⋀ (¬q(x) ⋁ p(x, y)) * Resulting prenex CNF